# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character with youtube api search

Tags: javascript, json, youtube

I'm using the [google api search javascript code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword) for searching for videos in my webpage,  but a bit modified. I leave the codes I use for the searching:

**search.js**

```
/*global gapi*/

// After the API loads, call a function to enable the search box.
function handleAPILoaded() {
    $('#search-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Search for a specified string.
function search() {
    var q = $('#query').val();
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        q: q,
        part: 'snippet'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
        $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
    });
}
// Search for a specified string.
function searchGET() {
    var q = $('#query').val();

    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+q+"HERE_MY_API_KEY";

    $.get(url, function(response) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
        $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
    });
}
```

Where I have put the `HERE_MY_API_KEY` is my API key, but Ihave removed it. Then I have the other file `search.html` containing this:

**search.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
    <label>
        <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/>
        <button id="search-button" disabled onclick="searchGET()">Search</button>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="search-container">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="search.js"></script>
<script src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleAPILoaded"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives me an `undefined` error, and with this, Ihave supposed I have to change the `JSON.stringify` with a `JSON.parse`, so, when changing it, it gives me another error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

var str = JSON.parse(response.result);
```

But in the console, I can see that the search query --> http://screencloud.net/v/tI3m

Then, what's wrong with it? What can I do if I want it to show my all the videos of the search query?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I use next code ( check your key and permissions )

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
    <label>
        <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/>
        <button id="search-button" disabled onclick="searchGET()">Search</button>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="search-container">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /*global gapi*/

// After the API loads, call a function to enable the search box.
function handleAPILoaded() {
    $('#search-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Search for a specified string.
function search() {
    var q = $('#query').val();
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        q: q,
        part: 'snippet'
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
        $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
    });
}
// Search for a specified string.
function searchGET() {
    var q = $('#query').val();

    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+q+"&key=AIzaSyB1uMymPwFOBRABjKGCf7YRf6RMUG6SUEY";

    $.get(url, function(response) {
        var str = JSON.stringify(response);
        $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
    });
}
</script>
<script src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleAPILoaded"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

try it [here](http://jsbin.com/jahuteho/1)

and get result

```
{"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","etag":"\"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/CwfaJ1oEKUon11qi2aCXuHjIjwM\"","nextPageToken":"CAUQAA","pageInfo":{"totalResults":1000000,"resultsPerPage":5},"items":[{"kind":"youtube#searchResult","etag":"\"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/m584ANOrYyzMPZvSmJYQub5jENU\"","id":{"kind":"youtube#channel","channelId":"UC9egiwuJsQZ0Cy2to5fvSIQ"},"snippet":{"publishedAt":"2013-11-29T09:26:45.000Z","channelId":"UC9egiwuJsQZ0Cy2to5fvSIQ","title":"Cat - Topic","description":"The domestic cat is a small, usually furry, domesticated, and carnivorous mammal. It is often called the housecat when kept as an indoor pet, or simply the c...","thumbnails":{"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/i/9egiwuJsQZ0Cy2to5fvSIQ/1.jpg"},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/i/9egiwuJsQZ0Cy2to5fvSIQ/mq1.jpg"},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/i/9egiwuJsQZ0Cy2to5fvSIQ/hq1.jpg"}},"channelTitle":"","liveBroadcastContent":"none"}},{"kind":"youtube#searchResult","etag":"\"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/W9FYP9wl4EdzxhVmdz7_NQtaD6I\"","id":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"7w6Riv_KAqM"},"snippet":{"publishedAt":"2014-03-09T12:57:29.000Z","channelId":"UCKy3MG7_If9KlVuvw3rPMfw","title":"Funny cats massaging and petting dogs - Cute animal compilation","description":"Some cats really love to massage and pet dogs, I wonder why they to that :P And looks like dogs don't mind that at all, they love it! Well there are of cours...","thumbnails":{"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7w6Riv_KAqM/default.jpg"},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7w6Riv_KAqM/mqdefault.jpg"},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7w6Riv_KAqM/hqdefault.jpg"}},"channelTitle":"wloltigerlolw2","liveBroadcastContent":"none"}},{"kind":"youtube#searchResult","etag":"\"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/TIAyNE-qv58TKdffi2KhU_jnk_o\"","id":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"FKkejo2dMV4"},"snippet":{"publishedAt":"2013-12-31T08:37:23.000Z","channelId":"UCfCXwyxWH3NiVdjavurcLwQ","title":"Funny Cats Compilation 20 min - Happy New Year 2014","description":"Happy New Year - Cats Compilation.","thumbnails":{"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FKkejo2dMV4/default.jpg"},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FKkejo2dMV4/mqdefault.jpg"},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FKkejo2dMV4/hqdefault.jpg"}},"channelTitle":"anacalderon1","liveBroadcastContent":"none"}},{"kind":"youtube#searchResult","etag":"\"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/JDIMyoezvLtntqLWAPSgYz3DhXM\"","id":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"QdIz_vzVJ0w"},"snippet":{"publishedAt":"2014-03-09T16:58:58.000Z","channelId":"UC7Hs0659Yc82h7Snhjnfd4g","title":"Black Cats - Cheghad Asheghetam OFFICIAL VIDEO HD","description":"Join Black Cats & all your favorite artists: http://fb.com/avangmusic artist: BLACK CATS song: CHEGHAD ASHEGHETAM label: AVANG MUSIC director: ALEX ...","thumbnails":{"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QdIz_vzVJ0w/default.jpg"},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QdIz_vzVJ0w/mqdefault.jpg"},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QdIz_vzVJ0w/hqdefault.jpg"}},"channelTitle":"avangmusic","liveBroadcastContent":"none"}},{"kind":"youtube#searchResult","etag":"\"BDC7VThyM9nfoSQm1_kOyhtJTEw/1Q6JkbgdyLLplxc6KxyYQ9-bdjM\"","id":{"kind":"youtube#video","videoId":"Kdgt1ZHkvnM"},"snippet":{"publishedAt":"2013-02-06T13:37:46.000Z","channelId":"UCb91Zl2MxLmUwriNocKeYnQ","title":"Epic Funny Cats 20 Minutes","description":"More funny cats -- http://www.catsbook.co Epic Funny Cats 20 Minutes http://www.catsbook.co http://www.facebook.com/Catsbook.co ...","thumbnails":{"default":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kdgt1ZHkvnM/default.jpg"},"medium":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kdgt1ZHkvnM/mqdefault.jpg"},"high":{"url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kdgt1ZHkvnM/hqdefault.jpg"}},"channelTitle":"CrazyCats2020","liveBroadcastContent":"none"}}]}
```

at page

Comment: Thank you! It worked! It outputs the youtube video object, just like I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I check your code - 
use

```
$.get(url, function(response) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(response);
    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
});
```

instead your code

```
$.get(url, function(response) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
});
```

Cause jquery put parsed data to success callback  function

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've tried it but it doesn't work... What else can I do?